# Currently trying to script a game and I don't understand how to debug this section of coding

Tags: debugging, lua, roblox

I'm following a youtube tutorial on scripting to create a game on roblox and whilst following it, "Status", the variable I use to identify a value decides to stop working (line39). My output box says the following:

> 21:16:36.197 - sword game.rbxl auto-recovery file was created
>
> 21:16:36.715 - ServerScriptService.MainScript:39: Expected ']' (to close '[' at line 37), got 'Status'
>
> 21:16:38.617 - ScriptNavigationHandler : No script currently available.

I haven't learned much about debugging code but if someone can shine some light on what is wrong that would greatly help me on my conquest to learn scripting during the fight against the invisible enemy.

```
-- Define varibles

local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")

local MapsFolder = ServerStorage:WaitForChild("Maps")

local Status = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Status")

local GameLength = 60

--Game loop

while true do
    
    Status.Value = "Waiting for enoughplayers"
    
    repeat wait(1) until game.Players.NumPlayers >=2
    
    Status.Value = "Intermission"
    
    wait(8)
    
    local plrs = {}
    
    for i, player in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
        if player then
            table.insert(plrs,player)  --Add each player into plrs table
        end
    end
    
    wait(2)
    
    local AvaliableMaps =MapsFolder:GetChildren()
    
    local ChosenMap = AvaliableMaps[math.random(1,#AvailableMaps)
    
    Status.Value = ChosenMap.Name "Chosen"
    
    local ClonedMap = ChosenMap:Clone()
    ClonedMap.Parent = workspace
    
    -- Teleport players to the map
    
    local SpawnPoints = ClonedMap:FindFirstChild("SpawnPoints")
    
    if not SpawnPoints then
        print("SpawnPoints not found!")
    end
    
    local AvailableSpawnPoints = SpawnPoints:GetChildren()
        
    for i, player in pairs(plrs) do
        if player then
            character = player.Character
            
            if character then
                -- Teleport them
                
                character:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart").CFrame = AvailableSpawnPoints[1].CFrame
                table.remove(AvailableSpawnPoints,1)
                
                -- Give Sword
                
                local Sword = ServerStorage.Sword:Clone()
                Sword.Parent = player.Backpack
                
                
                local GameTag = Instance.new("BoolValue")
                GameTag.Name = "GameTag"
                GameTag.Parent = player.Character
                
            else
                -- There is no character
                if not player then
                    table.remove(plrs,i)
                end
            end
        end
        
    end
    
end
```

Answer (score 4):

In

```
local ChosenMap = AvaliableMaps[math.random(1,#AvailableMaps)
```

you are missing the closing square bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Night94 has pointed out the correct fix for your broken code, but since your question is about learning to debug, I'll try to help you understand your error messages.

> 21:16:36.715 - ServerScriptService.MainScript:39: Expected ']' (to close '[' at line 37), got 'Status'

Let's break this down piece by piece :
*ServerScriptStorage.MainScript:39* this tells us where the file is, and on what line the error appeared.

So let's look at line 39 (through 41) you see :

```
local ChosenMap = AvaliableMaps[math.random(1,#AvailableMaps)

Status.Value = ChosenMap.Name "Chosen"
```

Next we have : *Expected ']' (to close '[' at line 37), got 'Status'*

This means that at some point, the code was expecting a square bracket to close the one that was opened at 37 : `AvaliableMaps[`, but instead it found the next line of code `Status`

So with these pieces of information, you should have all the pieces to understand what went wrong: A square bracket was opened, but never closed. It should go somewhere before the next line of code.

```
local ChosenMap = AvaliableMaps[math.random(1,#AvailableMaps)]
```